The SQL server database engine cannot obtain a lock resource at this time
I have a problem with the configuration of SQL Server. I have SQL Server 2019 with the latest cumulative update.
Max server memory is set to 40gb, maxdop is set to 0, and locks is set to 0. I have enough disk space.
The problem is when I execute this query:
insert into table A 
    select * 
    from table B

The problem happens:

The instance of the SQL Server database engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.

But when I execute the same query like this:
 select * 
 into table A 
 from table B 

The query works fine with no problem.
I tried to change to maximum memory config and the max dop to different values, but the problem persists.
